# Lock & Unlock buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a script which locks and unlock 2 buttons. If the divs are shown then lock the button "Tout déplier" and unlock the button "Tout plier", but if the divs are hidden then lock the button "tout plier" and unlock the button "Tout deplier".

My code, the buttons :

```
<input  type="button" name="answer" class="Button"  value="Tout plier" onclick="hideDiv()" /> 
<input  type="button" name="answer" class="Button" value="Tout déplier" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

The javascript for show and hide the divs :

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('content_caract_1').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_2').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_3').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_4').style.display = "block";
}

function hideDiv() {
   document.getElementById('content_caract_1').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_3').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_4').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Using classes would be more appropriate than having indexed IDs.

Comment: And even the code is not complete! Where is `div` related code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By lock and unlock I am assuming disabling and enabling button. If I am correct please try code below this might help.

```js
function showDiv($this) {
            enableAllButtons();
            $this.disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('content_caract_1').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_2').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_3').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_4').style.display = "block";
   }
    function hideDiv($this) {
        enableAllButtons();
            $this.disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('content_caract_1').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_3').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_4').style.display = "none";
  }
  function enableAllButtons(){
      var buttons = document.getElementsByName('answer');
      for(i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
      {
          var tempButton = buttons[i];
          tempButton.disabled = false;
      }
  }
```

```html
     <input  type="button" name="answer" class="Button"  value="Tout plier" onclick="hideDiv(this)" /> 
<input  type="button" name="answer" class="Button" value="Tout déplier" onclick="showDiv(this)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

set the `disabled` property of the buttons accordingly.

```js
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('content_caract_1').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_2').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_3').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_4').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('btnShow').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('btnHide').disabled = false;
}
function hideDiv() {
   document.getElementById('content_caract_1').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_3').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('content_caract_4').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('btnShow').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById('btnHide').disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input id="btnHide" type="button" name="answer" class="Button"  value="Tout plier" onclick="hideDiv()" /> 
<input id="btnShow" type="button" name="answer" class="Button" value="Tout déplier" onclick="showDiv()" disabled="true"/>
<div id="content_caract_1">content_caract_1</div>
<div id="content_caract_2">content_caract_2</div>
<div id="content_caract_3">content_caract_3</div>
<div id="content_caract_4">content_caract_4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it will be better to avoid the use of inline-event `onclick` and attach the click event in your JS part instead using `addEventListener()`.

Give your buttons an identifier and give your divs a common class instead if incremented ids (that will simplify the selectors for you), then use a common function that toggle the display like :

```js
var show_btn = document.querySelector('#show-div-btn');
var hide_btn = document.querySelector('#hide-div-btn');

show_btn.addEventListener('click', toggleDisplay);
hide_btn.addEventListener('click', toggleDisplay);

function toggleDisplay() {
  var display = this.id == 'show-div-btn' ? 'block' : 'none';
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.toggled_div');

  show_btn.disabled = (display == 'block');
  hide_btn.disabled = (display == 'none');

  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.display = display;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="hide-div-btn" type="button" name="answer" class="Button" value="Tout plier" />
<input id="show-div-btn" type="button" name="answer" class="Button" value="Tout déplier" />

<div class="toggled_div" id="content_caract_1">content_caract 1</div>
<div class="toggled_div" id="content_caract_2">content_caract 2</div>
<div class="toggled_div" id="content_caract_3">content_caract 3</div>
<div class="toggled_div" id="content_caract_4">content_caract 4</div>
```

Comment: Check this one @Nico

Answer (score 0):

For disable button you can use `disabled` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_disabled.asp). For toggle button after click you need `.setAttribute()` and `.removeAttribute()`.

Also I recomend you don't use `onclick` attribute for handle click event. Would be better if you replace `onclick` on `.addEventListener()`.
You can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) documentation for improve your code.

```js
var btnShow = document.getElementById('showDive');
var btnHide = document.getElementById('hideDive');

btnShow.addEventListener('click', showDiv);
btnHide.addEventListener('click', hideDiv);

function toggleButton(isShowed) {
  if (isShowed) {
    btnShow.setAttribute('disabled', '');
    btnHide.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    btnHide.setAttribute('disabled', '');
    btnShow.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}


function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('content_caract_1').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('content_caract_2').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('content_caract_3').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('content_caract_4').style.display = "block";
  toggleButton(true);
}

function hideDiv() {
  document.getElementById('content_caract_1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('content_caract_2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('content_caract_3').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('content_caract_4').style.display = "none";
  toggleButton(false);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="answer" class="Button" value="Tout plier" id="hideDive"/>
<input type="button" name="answer" class="Button" value="Tout déplier" id="showDive" disabled/>

<div id="content_caract_1">content_caract_1</div>
<div id="content_caract_2">content_caract_2</div>
<div id="content_caract_3">content_caract_3</div>
<div id="content_caract_4">content_caract_4</div>
```